# How do I evaluate $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(j-1)}}{(j-1)!}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

I am trying to prepare for my exams and want to calculate some matrix exponents $\exp(A)$ and wanted to do this with
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Right now I have
$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(j-1)}}{(j-1)!}$

$$ e^{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/e & \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(j-1)}}{(j-1)!} & 1 \\ 1 & 1/e & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1/e \end{bmatrix}.$$

I would greatly appreciate any tips or tricks I could use to progress further or even understand were I might have made mistakes.

Further info:
I arrived at my question through the following:

$A = (D+N)$

$$ (D+N)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n \choose k} D^{n-k} \cdot N^k = {n \choose 0} D^{n} \cdot N^0 + {n \choose 1} \cdot D^{n-1} \cdot N
=D^n+n \cdot D^{n-1}\cdot N$$
Since $N^n = 0$    $\forall n\geq 2$ only the first two sum elements matter.

Comment: Presumably each $i=0$ should be $j=0$? If so, please edit.

Comment: Remember, $e^x = 1+x + \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, you are correct, sorry!

Comment: For $j=0$ you have $(-1)!$ which is undefined. You may want to check the indices...

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth hmm, so I am not quite sure how to progress from that. I did use $e^x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!}$ to get all the other entries of the matrix exponent. So this is exactly my issue.

Comment: How did you arrive at your expression for $e^A$ actually? $A$ here is a Jordan matrix and its exponential should be upper triangular. There is a formula for exponential of Jordan matrix. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451276/matrix-exponential-for-jordan-canonical-form.

Comment: I seperated $A = (D+N)$ so that D became the identity matrix times (-1) and N had the singular non zero element at $n_{12} = 1$.
From there I went on with
$$(D+N)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n \choose k} D^{n-k} \cdot N^k$$
Since $N^k=0 for k \geq 2$ I got $$D^n + n\cdot D^{n-1}\cdot N$$
should I add that to the original question?

Comment: @jjagmath that is a good point. And one of my issues. I will try to write up my whole thought process, because I can't find an error.

Comment: Bear in mind also the natural extension of $1/n!$ is $1/(-1)!=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(j-1)}}{(j-1)!}\overset{k=j-1\ }{\longrightarrow}\sum_{k=-1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}=-\frac{1}{(-1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}.$$

In order to understand what $\frac{1}{(-1)!}$ means, we have to look at the [reciprocal Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function). We can express our term like this: $\frac{1}{(-1)!}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(0)}=0.$ If the starting point is actually $j=1$ and not $j=0$ we get the same result, since both outcomes are zero and do not change the value of the series.

Lastly, note that for all $x\in\mathbb R$, $\mathrm e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$, so our final solution is $e^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!