Fundamental Matrix of Ordinary Differential Equations system
I was reading Tyn Mynt U Ordinary Differential Equations.
I have to find the fundamental Matrix of solutions of the following matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix} 
Here the eigenvalue is 2 with multiplicity 3. But I always get stuck while procceeding further.
I am new to this course so guide me to the solution. Thanks in advance...

In this case, a basis of solutions is $e^{\lambda t},te^{\lambda t},t^2e^{\lambda t}$ with $\lambda = 2$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451276/matrix-exponential-for-jordan-canonical-form
